# Awk search expression and OFS

Tags: search, awk

I am trying to print sar output, excluding header with hostname and date. The following command is not able to exclude header lines and output field separator too:

```
sar -u|head -5|awk -F '
  BEGIN { hname="'"`hostname -s`"'"; hdt="'"`date +"%d-%b-%Y" `"'" ; OFS="," ;}
  { $1 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 ~ /[0-9]/ }
  { printf( "h=%-15s d=%11s 1=%8s 2=%2s 3=%-3s 4=%6.2f 5=%6.2f 6=%6.2f 7=%6.2f 8=%6.2f 9=%6.2f\n", hname, hdt, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 );}'
```

but when use the same search exp it work well !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```sh
sar -u|head -5|awk '
  BEGIN { hname="'"`hostname -s`"'"; hdt="'"`date +"%d-%b-%Y" `"'" ; OFS="," ;} 
  $1 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 ~ /[0-9]/
  { printf( "h=%-15s d=%11s 1=%8s 2=%2s 3=%-3s 4=%6.2f 5=%6.2f 6=%6.2f 7=%6.2f 8=%6.2f 9=%6.2f\n", hname, hdt, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 );}'
```

Note that this is untested, since I do not have the `sar` program installed.
If you paste some example output of that program, I can test the code and update my answer accordingly.

This is as closest to your code as possible and should work if I did not miss anything else.
The `-F` option you used did nothing since you did not specify a new *field separator* (`FS`).
Note that I removed the braces (curly brackets, `{...}`) around your *"search*" statement `$1 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 ~ /[0-9]/`.

An `awk` program consists of *patterns* and associated *actions*, that are performed for those *records* (without further options, each line is considered one *record*) matching the *pattern*. The *action* has to be enclosed in braces after the corresponding *pattern*.

So your code has three *actions*: The initialization that is associated to the special *BEGIN pattern* and thus performed once before reading any input and **two** actions that are performed for all *records* (i.e. lines) since they are not associated to any *pattern*: The first evaluates your search expression and the second prints the formatted *record*. Note, however, that these  two *actions* are **not** linked and the print action is performed no matter whether your search expression evaluated to true or false.

To understand what was wrong with your code you can run this verbose version:

```sh
sar -u|head -5|awk '
  BEGIN { hname="'"`hostname -s`"'"; hdt="'"`date +"%d-%b-%Y" `"'" ; OFS="," ;} 
  {print "search returned "($1 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 ~ /[0-9]/?"true.":"false.")}
  { printf( "h=%-15s d=%11s 1=%8s 2=%2s 3=%-3s 4=%6.2f 5=%6.2f 6=%6.2f 7=%6.2f 8=%6.2f 9=%6.2f\n", hname, hdt, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 );}'
```

This expands your first *action* to print the result of your search expression and you will see that the second (i.e. the `printf`) *action* is performed independently of that result.

By removing the braces around your search expression, you make that a *pattern* associated with the next *action*, the `printf` one. This way the `printf` is performed only for those *records* (i.e. lines) that match your search *pattern*.

Further note that your code gets more readable if you store the external commands' output in variables [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17276728/2451238) by [@jaypal singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/jaypal-singh), in the following achieved by initializing `awk` variables using the `-v` option:

```sh
sar -u|head -5|awk \
                -v hname="`hostname -s`" \
                -v hdt="`date +"%d-%b-%Y"`" \
                -v OFS="," \
               '
                $1 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 ~ /[0-9]/{
                 printf( "h=%-15s d=%11s 1=%8s 2=%2s 3=%-3s 4=%6.2f 5=%6.2f 6=%6.2f 7=%6.2f 8=%6.2f 9=%6.2f\n", hname, hdt, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 )
                }
               '
```

**Addendum:**

[As pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17276728/2451238) by [@jaypal singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/jaypal-singh), the *output field separator* (`OFS`) will not affect `prinft` so you might want to use comma (`,`) instead of space () in your `printf` statement instead of defining `OFS`:

```sh
sar -u|awk \
        -v hname="`hostname -s`" \
        -v hdt="`date +"%d-%b-%Y"`" \
       '
        $1 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 ~ /[0-9]/{
         printf( "h=%-15s,d=%11s,1=%8s,2=%2s,3=%-3s,4=%6.2f,5=%6.2f,6=%6.2f,7=%6.2f,8=%6.2f,9=%6.2f\n", hname, hdt, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 )
        }
       '
```

Note that this time I also removed `head` from the pipeline since you stated in a comment that this was just introduced for testing reasons and if it was not using the *record number* (`NR`) would have been better [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17276728/2451238) by [@jaypal singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/jaypal-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

```
$ hname=$(hostname -s)
$ hdt=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
$ $ sar -u | awk '$1~/[0-9]/&&$4~/[0-9]/&&NR<=5{print host,dat,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}' OFS="," host="$hname" dat="$hdt"
```

**Some pointers:**

- No need for `head`, you can control number of lines by using `NR` variable
- To use bash commands in `awk` you need to use `system()` or you can store bash commands in variable and call them in `awk` like we have done above.
- The **output separator variables** `OFS` and `ORS` have no effect on `printf` statements

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  
- I used **head** temporarily, just to test with few lines. Later on it will be removed. Thanks for reminding me NR variable.  
- I try to use system() in awk but it return 0 (successful code) in result, not actual output.   
- I need printf bcoz of fixed format output  
- My major concern is search, why my search is not working?